# Best way to remove an object from an array in Processing

Tags: processing

I really wish Processing had *push* and *pop* methods for working with Arrays, but since it does not I'm left trying to figure out the best way to remove an object at a specific position in an array. I'm sure this is as basic as it gets for many people, but I could use some help with it, and I haven't been able to figure much out by browsing the Processing reference.

I don't think it matters, but for your reference here is the code I used to add the objects initially:

```
Flower[] flowers = new Flower[0];

for (int i=0; i < 20; i++)
{
    Flower fl = new Flower();
    flowers = (Flower[]) expand(flowers, flowers.length + 1);
    flowers[flowers.length - 1] = fl;
}
```

For the sake of this question, let's assume I want to remove an object from position 15. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your best bet is to use arraycopy. You can use the same array for src and dest. Something like the following (untested):

```
// move the end elements down 1
arraycopy(flowers, 16, flowers, 15, flowers.length-16);
// remove the extra copy of the last element
flowers = shorten(flowers);
```

Answer (score 6):

You may also want to consider using [ArrayList](http://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html) which has more methods available than a plain array.

You can remove the fifteenth element by using `myArrayList.remove(14)`

Comment: I found this to be the easiest way to tackle the problem.

Comment: Does this work for an array of objects? I get "Cannot invoke remove(int) on the array type filename.SomeClass[]"

Answer (score 1):

I made a funtion which basically switches the index to be removed to the last and then shortens it.

```
int[] removeByIndex(int[] array, int index) {
  int index2 = array.length-1;
  int old = array[index];
  array[index] = array[index2];
  array[index2] = old;
  array = shorten(array);
  return array;
}

yourarray = removeByIndex(yourarray , arrayindex);
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] myArray = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}; 

String[] RemoveItem(String[] arr, int n) {
  if (n < arr.length-1) {
    arrayCopy(subset(arr, n+1), 0, arr, n, arr.length-1-n);
  }
  arr = shorten(arr);
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

I know this question was asked a long time ago however it seems a lot of people are still looking for the answer. I just wrote this. I tested it a few ways and it seems to run the way I wanted it to.

```
var yourArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];                                // use your array here
var removeIndex = 1;                                       // item to get rid of 

var explode = function(array, index) {                     // create the function
    var frontSet = subset(array, 0, index - 1);            // get the front
    var endSet = subset(array, index , array.length - 1);  // get the end
    yourArr = concat(frontSet, endSet);                    // join them
};

explode(yourArr, removeIndex);                             // call it on your array
```

That is one way. I guess you could loop through the array as well. Something like ...

```
var yourArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var removeIndex = 2;
var newArr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < yourArr.length; i++) {
    if(i < removeIndex) {
        append(newArr, yourArr[i]);
    } else if(i > removeIndex) {
        append(newArr, yourArr[i]);
    }
}

yourArr = newArr;
```

... think that should work too. Hope this helps anybody who needs it.

Comment: Please note that Processing uses Java syntax. This answer uses JavaScript syntax so it isn't really a valid answer.